# What is maximum safe operating temperature for my Intel Pentium (R) D 3.00Ghz?

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I am using speedfan. can someone tell me how to configure it properly for my Pentium?

Comment: You shouldn't have to do "anything".  It should detect everything automatically.  if it does not then its a bug in the program.  Speedfan has no known problems with the Pentium D.

Comment: Pentium Ds run exceptionally hot (one of the few chips I've had serious trouble keeping reasonably cool). if your fans are running at 100%, and you still have trouble, you may need to get a better heatsink, and review your cases air flow strategy.

Answer (score 2):

Its hard to know, which temperature is the highest recommended, if we dont know, which 3 Ghz Pentium D processor you are using exactly.

So here a list of temperatures for every 3.0 Ghz Pentium D processors:

- [Pentium D 830 is 69.8°C](http://www.heatsink-guide.com/maxtemp.htm)
- [Pentium D 925 is 62.3°C](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Pentium_D/Intel-Pentium%20D%20925%20HH80553PG0804MN%20%28BX80553925%29.html)
- [Pentium D 930 is 62.3°C](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Pentium_D/Intel-Pentium%20D%20930%20HH80553PG0804M%20%28BX80553930%20-%20BX80553930T%29.html)

But speedfan should do everything without your help. You shouldn't have to configure anything unless the temperature is higher than these 69.8°C.

Comment: 69.8 is great, unless he's using a Intel Pentium D 930 
(4M Cache, 3.00 GHz, 800 MHz FSB), which has a Tcase of 63.4°C (not 69.8).  Without knowing EXACTLY which Pentium D is in question, it's hard to know which (suggested) maximums to pass along.

Comment: @techie007 You are absolutely right. I've updated my answer with a list.

Comment: Nice..  Note: [ark.intel.com](http://ark.intel.com) is the best place to get Intel CPU specs (for future reference ;) )

Comment: Thx. Good to know. I've took cpu-world as reference. But thanks. I will use that in the future. :)